# Diferente logo por "company code" en un sapscript configurado desde la transacción FBZP

Tags: sap, abap

Escenario de impresión desde la transacción F110 de un sapscript (YSTP_F2021_PYADV) configurado en la transacción FBZP, en donde el Head Line configurado es el siguiente:

```
/*      define distance of logo from left margin of HEADER-window
/:      DEFINE &LOGO_LEFT& = '53'
/:      DEFINE &LOGO_LEFT_UNIT& = 'CH'
/*      use empty lines to position logo from top of HEADER-window
/
/                                                  
/*      Call monochrome logo ("BMON") that can be printed by
/*      PCL-5, PostScript, Prescribe and SAPWIN printers
/:      INCLUDE ADRS_HEADER_LOGO_BMON OBJECT TEXT ID ADRS LANGUAGE E
```

Revisando la SO10 el logo en texto "ADRS_HEADER_LOGO_BMON" contiene un logo genérico.

El problema que presenta el sapscript es que según la selección del "company code" presenta un logo diferente, entonces no encuentro en dónde poder cambiar dicha validación que debe de hacer, o dónde ver la llamada a un logo normal ya que el logo que se presenta está en la SE78.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,

Normalmente suele haber más de un "Company code" en el sistema por lo que cada uno tendrá asignado su LOGO corporativo.

No sé que perfil tienes en SAP pero usando la ST05 para ver la traza puedes identificar rapidamente el Report que se encarga de displayarte el sapscript.

Lanza ST05 he imprime el documento, desactiva la traza y diplaya resultados, tiene que haber algún report 'Z' en el listado resultante, ahí se encuentra la validación que mostrará un logo u otro.

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Haz que tu INCLUDE llame a un texto distinto de manera dinámica, creando una variable global donde colocas el nombre del Texto dependiento de la compañía.

En la SO10 creas un Texto distinto para cada compañía, cada uno con su logo.

Comment: Añade código para que la respuesta sea aceptada

Answer (score 0):

la solución es agregar un case dentro del sapscript llamando a diferentes logos según sociedad:

`/: CASE &campo sociedad, digamos T001-BUKRS&`

`/: WHEN 'XXX1'`

`/* Incluimos el logo de la sociedad XXX1`

`/: INCLUDE LOGO_XXX1 OBJECT TEXT ID ADRS LANGUAGE E`

`/: WHEN 'XXX2'`

`/* Incluimos el logo de la sociedad XXX2`

`/: INCLUDE LOGO_XXX2 OBJECT TEXT ID ADRS LANGUAGE E`

`/: ENDCASE`

Saludos!